# A sequential definition of the derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

For a function $f$ differentiable at a point $c$, take sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ with $x_n < c < y_n$ for all $n$ and both of those sequences converge to $c$. The problem is to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n -x_n}=f'(c)$$

The intuition is clear, but I'm struggling to provide a rigorous argument. One approach I was considering was to suppose the equality doesn't hold and then argue that this would imply either $f(y_n)$ or $f(x_n)$ doesn't converge to $f(c)$ and thus the function $f$ could not be continuous which is a contradiction since we assumed $f$ was differentiable. I don't think that argument is valid, and if there is a direct approach, I would be interested to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have \begin{align}
\frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}&=\frac{f(y_n)-f(c)}{y_n-x_n}+\frac{f(c)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}\\ \ \\
&=\frac{f(y_n)-f(c)}{y_n-c}\,\frac{y_n-c}{y_n-x_n}+\frac{f(c)-f(x_n)}{c-x_n}\,\frac{c-x_n}{y_n-x_n}\\ \ \\
\end{align}
If you now fix $\varepsilon>0$ and choose $n$ big enough so that
$$
\left|\frac{f(y_n)-f(c)}{y_n-c}-f'(c)\right|<\varepsilon\ \ \ \text{ and } 
\left|\frac{f(c)-f(x_n)}{c-x_n}-f'(c)\right|<\varepsilon,
$$
then
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}-f'(c)\right|&=
\left|
\left(\frac{f(y_n)-f(c)}{y_n-c}-f'(c)\right)\,\frac{y_n-c}{y_n-x_n}+\left(\frac{f(c)-f(x_n)}{c-x_n}-f'(c)\right)\,\frac{c-x_n}{y_n-x_n}
\right|\\ \ \\
&\leq\varepsilon\,\frac{y_n-c}{y_n-x_n}+\varepsilon\,\frac{c-x_n}{y_n-x_n}=\varepsilon.
\end{align}
It is key here that $y_n-c\geq0$, $y_n-x_n>0$, and $c-x_n\geq0$. And also that
$$
f'(c)=f'(c)\,\frac{y_n-c}{y_n-x_n}+f'(c)\,\frac{c-x_n}{y_n-x_n}
$$
since
$$
\frac{y_n-c}{y_n-x_n}+\frac{c-x_n}{y_n-x_n}=1.
$$

Comment: That's a good proof. Just out of curiosity, do you happen to know if there is a way to complete a contradiction proof in the style described above? or did that approach seem entirely mistaken? obviously with such a nice argument like the one you presented it's not necessary, but I'm curious nonetheless.

Comment: I cannot really imagine a different argument (not saying it doesn't exist, of course). If I try to go with your approach, I end up using mine somehow (to rewrite things in terms of the known limits) and so the proof becomes more convoluted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You write it is key that $y_n-x_n\geq 0$, so their difference can equal $0$? More generally, does your above argument work for $x_n\leq c\leq y_n$?

Comment: No, if the difference is zero the expression is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, don't we need $y_n-c>0$ and $c-x_n>0$ as well, i.e. strict inequality rather than non-strict?

Comment: Yes. $ \ \ \ \ $