# How to prove that this limit approaches derivative of f at point c?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Suppose that $f$ is a function that is differentiable  at point $c$. Sequences $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ have the property that for each $n$, $a_n < c < b_n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = c$. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f(b_n) - f(a_n)}{b_n - a_n} = f'(c)$.

I tried to do some manipulation inside the limit of left side to make it related to $f'(c)$, but it didn't work. Can someone give me a hint of the solution?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/817944/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1961598/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cdfrac%7Bf(b_n)%20-%20f(a_n)%7D%7Bb_n%20-%20a_n%7D%20%3D%20f%27(c)%24&p=1)

Comment: Sorry I could'nt find these answers. Thank you for your help.